# WiX XML Write with New Line

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to write to an xml file, but each write just keeps writing to the same line, but I want each new entry to be a new line. Is that possible?

What's happening:

```
<item>value1</item><item>value2</item><item>value3</item>
```

What I want:

```
<item>value1</item>
<item>value2</item>
<item>value3</item>
```

My Code:

```
    <util:XmlFile Id="Add" Permanent="yes" Action="createElement" ElementPath="path" File=".config" Name="item" Value="[VALUE]" />
```

Comment: Not to be cynical but does it really matter?

Comment: It shouldn't, but sometimes it does.  I've seen ASP.NET bugs where <Clear /> and <Clear></Clear>  are not the same.  See: https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?170779-XML-File-Update-Changes-The-Way-Tags-Are-Closed

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the file after all your modifications have been done. To do that you will have to schedule a [custom action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html) to run just before the installation finishes. That happens in the InstallExecuteSequence with the InstallFinalize action. Running a custom action at that stage makes it a deferred custom action. Deferred custom actions cannot simply work with the session values of the installer. You will have to [pass values to them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa370543.aspx) with a [type 51](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa368237(v=vs.85).aspx) custom action. You will have to use that type 51 custom action to pass the file path of the xml file you want to format to your executing custom action. You can then access this variable by using the [CustomActionData Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(v=vs.100).aspx) and manipulate the file with the help of the [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [XmlTextWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) classes. See the following example:

```
<Fragment>
<CustomAction Id="Type51XmlFileName" Property="FormatAlteredFile" Value="UnformattedXmlFileName=[INSTALLFOLDER]File.xml" />
<CustomAction Id="FormatAlteredFile" BinaryKey="AlterXmlFile.DLL" DllEntry="FormatAlteredFile" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
</Fragment>
```

DTF Custom Action:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult FormatAlteredFile(Session session)
{
    string xmlFileName;
    if ( session.CustomActionData.TryGetValue("UnformattedXmlFileName", out xmlFileName) )
    {
        if (File.Exists(xmlFileName))
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlReader input = XmlReader.Create(xmlFileName))
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(input);
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
                XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = null;
                try
                {
                    xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
                    xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    doc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (xmlTextWriter != null)
                    {
                        xmlTextWriter.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(xmlFileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(stringBuilder);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ActionResult.NotExecuted;
                }
            }
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
    return ActionResult.NotExecuted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XML document object models typically format the document in a certain way. As long as it's XML complaint it *shouldn't* matter.   So either fix the app so it doesn't matter or roll your own custom actions for updating the XML.  (That is a lot more work then it sounds.)

Comment: XML formatting can in fact matter if a human being is going to be looking at it (either for debugging or intended usage).  If the xml file is only going to be viewed by a machine then the whitespace/formatting really should not matter.